# Show product's image in “Orders” page - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working with WC for the first time and I am chasing my tail with this one.

In "Orders" page where customer's can see all the purchases they've made the array shows some basic info about the order.
I need to also show the image of the product the customer bought.

Orders seems to be custom posts, but how do I get the image product?

I realize the question is too vague. Any pointers would be a big great help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Orders are custom post types of `shop_order` type. Orders do not have thumbnails themselves, but orders have a list of products that were purchased and each product has the possibility of a thumbnail.

You can see in the [`order-details.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details.php#L25-33) template how to get all the items/products associated with any order object... `$order->get_items()`

This returns an array of data that is stored in separate database tables. With the `$item` variable you can get the original product and you can see in the linked template that the `$product` variable that is being sent to the `order-details-item.php` is defined as `order->get_product_from_item( $item )`.

Anyway, once you have the `$product` object you can use `$product->get_image()` to retrieve the product's image.

As a simplified example, this would show the thumbnails for all the products purchased in order 999.

```
$order_id = 999;
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );
        echo $product->get_image();
}
```

Nesting this inside of your loop:

```
foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) { 
   $order = wc_get_order(); 
   $order->populate( $customer_order ); 
   foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $product' = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );
            echo $product->get_image();
    }
}
```

Though normally, the `order-details.php` template should have links to an overview of each individual order.

Comment: Thank you @helgatheviking! Can I ask you one more thing? In the theme I use I have this array `foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
 $order = wc_get_order();
 $order->populate( $customer_order );
 $item_count = $order->get_item_count();`
How can I combine it with your code?

Comment: You could 'nest'  the `foreach` loops.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. You are a savior though! One note: in your code you write `$product' =` I am new to php but  you have a quote there and it returns an error. As soon as the quote is removed the error is removed as well.

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing? How could I also include the short description when showing the order?

Comment: The short description is merely the excerpt for the product, same as for regular posts.

Comment: Yes, I have figured this out and I am already displaying it in the catalog using `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` but nothing I try works for the orders page.

Comment: Orders don't have excerpts, so it would need to be in the same loop that is getting the product images. Please create a new question.